# Converting an FQL query into a web service

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a query that I can use in the FQL engine at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I would like to utilize this in Java as a web service (HTTP Get?) in order to retrieve the same results. I can probably devise a way to fetch an access token out of my existing database. Here is the query:

```
select application_id from developer where developer_id = 54777****
```

It requires only an access token as well as the value in the where column. I can fetch both in my DB. But, I would like to figure out how to write this up as a web service that I can use in the browser (not even a curl) just so I know that the concept will work before I code up all the objects and conditions in Java.

Can anyone help me out with the web service URL? Currently when I try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/applications/developer/access_token=xxxx
```

I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all, never ever give your access token, secondly, try the same with extended access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting the "?" that has to go before URL parameters. The correct URL for you would be:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/applications/developer/?access_token=xxxxxxx
(Note the "?" after "/developer/")

Also, you should really avoid posting your own access tokens. This one's expired, but you should never publicly post your token.